# In Flutter, How can I make a widget "hover and follow" another widget in a Stack, without latency?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My demand is demonstrated in the following pic, I need the hovering box to "overflow" the underlying box:

[image: A translucent box hovers and follows an item in the ListView while the list scrolls]

My current implementation is to use Stack and Positioned.fromRect, get the Rect using the global key of item, then while it scroll I call setState to refresh it.

```dart
      Stack(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                physics: NoFlingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                        child: RectGetter(
                            key: keys[index],
                            child: SizedBox.square(
                              dimension: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                              child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green, border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                                  child: Text(index.toString())),
                            ))),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: 20,
              ),
              Positioned.fromRect(
                  rect: rect,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
                      onTap: () => toggleColor(),
                      onVerticalDragUpdate: (update) {
                        _controller
                            .jumpTo(_controller.offset - update.delta.dy);
                      },
                      child: Container(color: color)))
            ],
          ),

    getRect(int? index) {
        if (index == null) return Rect.zero;
        var rect = RectGetter.getRectFromKey(keys[index]);
        rect = rect?.inflate(10);
        return rect ?? Rect.zero;
    }
    Rect get rect => getRect(selectedIndex);
```

However this method is laggy, it noticeably rubberbands while I scroll. Are there any better solution regarding this feature demand?

I am aware of inline OverflowBox solution (The items in ListView have OverflowBox in them), but the overflowing parts of it cannot be hit-tested by flutter's internal design, which is against my needs.

Comment: check `CompositedTransformTarget` / `CompositedTransformFollower` widgets

Comment: @pskink works like a charm, I already implemented a demo, will post a dartpad and answer my own question.

Comment: great, at first those widgets sound mysterious, but they do their job well ;-)

Comment: @pskink at first the usage of Overlay really scared me off, thought it's imperative like navigation 1.0. now I know Stack and Overlay are the only correct, no-hack ways to handle z-index in flutter. OverflowBox is merely a visual hack.

Comment: there is another feature request where i tried CustomMultiChildLayout, but it cannot shrink to it's child's size, had to dig into RenderObject. Flutter official need to make more advanced tutorials on things like this. what I wanted was exactly implemented by flutter_boxy (certain child dominant the cross-axis size), this package did it by extending MultiChildRenderObjectWidget.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @pskink, CompositedTransformTarget / CompositedTransformFollower is the solution.

TLDR: If HitTest/GestureDetector is needed on the "overflowing parts", and its position and size is dynamic, always use Overlay + CompositedTransformFollower!

See [DartPad of my implementation](https://dartpad.dev/dcc21a3e10f4705f8a40b2cef0712831)

Explanation: Stack **is** Overlay under the hood, however Stack trades flexibility for convenience.

CompositedTransformTarget/CompositedTransformFollower pair can be used in Overlay to link Widgets in different layers by their position and align them with targetAnchor/followerAnchor parameter in the Follower widget.

The Follower can also get the size of its Target by accessing LayerLink#leaderSize.

This method does not incur the no-HitTest issue of OverflowBox either.

Comment: i took a look at your code again and was very confused why you call `setState` in `onPointerMove:` callback? you dont need it, which means you dont need  `Listener` widget and thus rebuilding the whole ui tree on each finger move - now your code will move at light speed ;-)

Comment: @pskin that's the remain of my last approach where I get Rect from a GlobalKey, it has to be removed now in this approach. There is still another problem, how can I make the scroll transitive from the overlay to the underlying ListView? Now I have to use the imperative "controller.jumpTo" in the gesture detector to direct the vertical drag to the underlying ListView.

Comment: And there is another feature demand that i think worth asking as another stackoverflow question, about the Draggable widget, how can I implement a custom Draggable so that it can become draggable when I toggle on certain conditions (but within one input sequence?), just like how I can press and hold then drag and reorder an app icon in Android Laucher?

Comment: ignore pointer is the way! but on dartpad (web environment), this implementation's behavior is strange, you cannot drag scroll outside the overlay but you can wheel scroll, while you can't wheel scroll the overlay but you can drag scroll. maybe we should wrap the hovering overlay entry into something?

Comment: sorry I didn't correctly refresh my dartpad, so that's a false alarm. new problem is ignore pointer will block my gesture detector from receiving events (the toggle color and height increase thing), so maybe I will need to customize my own gesture recognizer...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244144/discussion-between-linkfting-and-pskink).